# ¿Para qué es el branch “gh-pages” que aparece en muchos repos de GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Últimamente explorando algunos repositorios de GitHub, veo que muchos de ellos tienen un branch llamado “*gh-pages*”. Me ha llamado mucho la atención ya que cuando lo vi por primera vez no le di importancia… pero cuando ya lo vi en varios repos me causó curiosidad y pensé que para algo ha de servir.

¿Alguien sabe para qué es este branch? La única documentación que vi al respecto es esta: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/ pero no me queda muy claro para qué es.

Comment: La rama "gh-pages" la tienen los repositorios antiguos. Desde agosto de 2016 ya no son requeridas. Referencia [Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta rama `gh-pages` te permite y es una excelente forma de mostrar tus proyectos al mundo a través de un sitio web. Ya sea para un portafolio, `landing page` e incluso para crear un `blog`. Todo de manera gratuita y con repositorios ilimitados. Desgraciadamente no podemos usar código del lado del servidor (`Python`, `Ruby`, `PHP`, etc.).

Así que si tú sólo quieres mostrar un proyecto (Front-end), `GitHub Pages` es tu mejor opción.

Si quieres documentarte mas, te recomiendo este super articulo que es un paso a paso, para lograr lo dicho anteriormente.

[Paso a paso - Articulo Git Hub Pages](https://platzi.com/blog/github-pages/)

Answer (score 9):

**¡Sitios web para nosotros y nuestros proyectos!**

`Github` nos da la posibilidad de generar un sitio web a partir de nuestra organización o proyecto, muy útil para portafolios, blogs y todo tipo de páginas del lado del front-end(totalmente gratis).

**Cómo creamos la rama(branch) `gh-pages`**

Abrimos la consola y nos posicionamos dentro de la carpeta de nuestro proyecto y tecleamos:

```
$ git branch gh-pages
```

Esto nos creara la rama(branch) `gh-pages` en nuestro proyecto. Por último, hay que subirlo a nuestro repositorio remoto(`Github`) haciendo un push de esta manera:

```
$ git push origin gh-pages
```

Ahora ya puedes ingresar a tu sitio por medio de http://nombreDeUsuario.github.io/repositorio

**Ventajas**

Enseña tus proyectos al mundo por ejemplo CV, Landing Page, página de tu negocio, Documentación, etcétera. Es una excelente forma de que vean tu trabajo `front-end`sin tener la necesidad de comprar y/o usar un dominio.

**Desventajas**

Por desgracia no podemos usar código del lado del servidor (`Python`, `Ruby`, `PHP`, etc.). Así que si tú sólo quieres mostrar un proyecto (`Front-end`), `GitHub` Pages es tu mejor opción.

**Ejemplos de usuarios que usan Github pages**

http://rosadintv.github.io/

http://routerkeygen.github.io/

http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/

**Más Información**

https://pages.github.com/

https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/

Comment: Me pareció una respuesta bastante más completa que la otra (principalmente por mencionar la URL en la que se puede ver el sitio relacionado a ese branch). ¿Por qué los votos negativos?

Comment: No entiendo los votos negativos en esta respuesta. Gracias por tu aportación @LuisGómez

Comment: He votado positivo porque la respuesta es muy completa, pero en mi opinión tiene una *malísima* redacción. Espero que esto se corrija.

Comment: Editado - Cómo crear la rama `gh-pages`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus increíbles aportes. Ya me queda mucho más claro el tema. 
Un abrazo desde Colombia